# what's the best structure when use many keys and one value?

Tags: c#, dictionary, unity-game-engine, data-structures

I'm making an assetbundle loader. now I'm using `Resources.Load(path)` but it will be changed to `MyResources.Load(path)`.

`MyResources.Load(path)` will work same `Resources.Load(path)` when i develop and will find assetbundle name from path and return an object when it release.

so, now I'm using following.

```
hashAssetBundle.Add("Sword/red_sword.prefab", "weapon");
hashAssetBundle.Add("Sword/blue_sword.prefab", "weapon");
hashAssetBundle.Add("Gun/red_gun.prefab", "weapon");
hashAssetBundle.Add("Gun/blue_gun.prefab", "weapon");
```

and use like following and the reason why I use like it is compatibility and convinience of development.

```
goSword = MyResources.Load<GameObject>("Sword/red_sword");
```

problem is the 4000 keys. I want a better data structure.
help me!

ps. sorry for English.

Comment: What do you consider "a better data-structure"? What is so bad about the current one? What is your problem with it? Do you get errors? Unexpected results? Does the code run slow? Did you *measure* that?

Comment: sorry, it's just guess. overlapped value and many keys make me confuse.

Comment: What is the *value* in this Key-Value structure *used for.* The key is obviously the resource you want to load, but you don't tell us what the *value* represents.

Answer (score 0):

Small suggestion on resource loading. Cant you load the asset folder instead of individual asset itself.

```
Add("Sword", "weapon");
```